# C# script(child object) not allowing me to access in another script (which is the parent object) unity

Tags: c#, object, inheritance, unity-game-engine

I can access the object from the  script however I want to directly change values of the object in the  script and this is not allowing me to. Here is my scrip for the main script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using RTS;

public class QuestionMenu : MonoBehaviour {
public struct Question{
    public string questionText;
    public string answer;
    public string solution1;
    public string solution2;
    public string solution3;
}
//public void QuestionObject(string QuestionText, string answer, string solution1, string solution2, string solution3){
    //Debug.Log ("lol");
//}
public Question QuestionObject = new Question();
Canvas canvas;
public UserInput Player;
public Text QuestionText;
public Text Button1;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    canvas = GetComponent<Canvas>();
    canvas.enabled = false;
    ResourceManager.QuestionMenuOpen = false;
    //instruction = GetComponent<Text>();
    //Debug.Log (QuestionText);
    Button1.text = "Crazy";
    QuestionText.text = "Yo Bro";
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    ////Debug.Log (QuestionObject.questionText);
    if(ResourceManager.QuestionMenuOpen == true){
        //QuestionObject.questionText = "bloo";
        Pause ();
        //QuestionText.text = "Question 1) Differentiate 3x\u2074 + 2x.";
        //Button1.text = "12x\u00B3 + 2";
    }
}

public void Pause (){
    canvas.enabled = true;
    Player.enabled = false;
    Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
    Cursor.visible = true;
    //QuestionObject = Questions.QuestionObject;
    Debug.Log (QuestionObject.questionText);
    QuestionText.text = QuestionObject.questionText;
    //ResourceManager.QuestionMenuOpen = true;
    }

void Resume (){
    Cursor.visible = false;
    canvas.enabled = false;
    Player.enabled = true;
    Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
    ResourceManager.QuestionMenuOpen = false;
    }


}
```

And here is the script for my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class QuestionScript : MonoBehaviour {
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    QuestionMenu.QuestionObject.answer = "asdf";
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Edit: I wish to access the Object QuestionObject from the scrip shown above here is a screen shot of the gameObject which has both scripts attached to it

[image]

Comment: you want to access the Question struct defined in parent class in child class?

Comment: Yep - I want to change the values within the gameObject called QuestionObject (defined immidiately after the struct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the Inheritance concept. When you declare a class like you do here :

```
public class Questions : QuestionMenu {
```

it means Question class has the same functions and variables with QuestionMenu class (I assume they are all public). But it doesnt mean you can connect 2 GameObjects to each other like that. When you set Question script on Parent that is another object (I mean Question object). And when you set QuestionMenu script on the Child it is totaly different and new object. Also they have no connection with eachother. What you should do is :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Questions {
public Questions dpoint; // u can set this on unity editor by just draging and dropping the parent object here.

void Start () {
    //or you can get it from code I belive
    dpoint = transform.parent.GetComponent<Question>();
    QuestionObject.questionText = "asd";

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {    
    base.QuestionObject.questionText = "asd2";
}

}
```

I hope that I didnt misunderstand your question..

Comment: Thanks I understand it better now but how can I access the GameObject QuestionObject as it is not in the scene - is there a way of accessing it like this - as I used your code and it could not find Question

Comment: I think even im confused now as to what the question was in the first place.

Comment: So you mean the parent object doesnt have Question script ?

Comment: Probably we are missing what he exactly ask

Comment: Edited it at the bottom to make it more clear and updated the 2nd script code to show my current attempts (note the scripts in the gameObject are located at the bottom right of the image) - also the QuestionObject is now declared as static as LumbusterTick suggestion

Comment: Actually I solved it by doing all those things - I'm not sure who to give answer to as you both helped me get the answer - sir walek explained inheritance which stopped me from trying stupid things and lumbuster showed static as well as helped me think about the code (well both of you did) so who do i give answer to???

Comment: well mr walek is a senior give him the answer and he explained with clean code . Inheritance > static variables.

Comment: Sorry I was afk. If you fixed your problem it doesn't matter mate.

Answer (score 2):

USE public static Question QuestionObject = new Question();

then you can access and change its values in child class like this

Parentclass.QuestionObject.value

Comment: Ok - ive done that but now I get an error unless i take out the line base.QuestionObject.questiontext, also using just QuestionObject.questionText still doesn't seem to be making a difference - perhaps the child script is never called - and if so how could i call it from the parent script

Comment: you call other scripts like how @Sir.Walek answered.

Comment: what do you mean perhaps the child script is never called? If its attached to a gameobject and active in the scene its being  run and will change the value .